# How to set SelectCommand to change 'WHERE' to logged in user

Tags: sql, asp.net

I've been working on webforms and per user data on ASP.NET where if a user logs in, they get their data.

I have a table where it takes the sqldatasource from an asp markup code:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection.ProviderName %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [first_name], [last_name], [weight_data] FROM [userData] 
        WHERE [email]='test@test.com';">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

I can get the currently logged in email string through `<%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName() %>`

How would I put that into the WHERE email statement so I can take currently logged in user's email and replace it with 'test@test.com' to match it on the SQL table to get the other data?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possibly dupe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10540470/dynamic-query-in-asp-net-where-clause-in-sqldatasource

Comment: Thanks for the formatting. Still unsure of how I'd replace it from looking at the possible dupe. Do I do the same thing he does with selectparameters with <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName() %> inside? Quite new to asp.net so replacing variables are confusing. Thanks bud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different ways like:
You can use the built in OnSelecting parameter of asp:SqlDataSource

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqldsExample" runat="server"
    SelectCommand="SELECT [first_name], [last_name], [weight_data] FROM [userData] 
            WHERE [email]=@UserEmail"
    OnSelecting="SqldsExample_Selecting">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="UserEmail" Type="String"/>
</SelectParameters>
```

In code-behind

```
protected void SqldsExample_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceCommandEventArgs e)
{
         e.Command.Parameters["UserEmail"].Value = Context.User.Identity.GetUserName();
}
```

**Another way:**

```
SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("@UserEmail", Context.User.Identity.GetUserName());
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot bud. For some reason it shows up as. 'Must declare the scalar variable "@UserEmail".'

Comment: Did you try both ways ?

Comment: exclude "@" i.e. SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters.Add("UserEmail", Context.User.Identity.GetUserName());

Comment: I added @ on the 1st way and it worked! You're brilliant. Thank you very much.

Comment: My vote ups don't display yet, but be assured I did! Have a wonderful day mate.